Video Game Probability Calculation
I'm making a video game and was hoping for some help with a probability problem.
The player can level up, and upon doing so, they are given the choice of 3 upgrade options, randomly chosen from a pool of 20 options. Each option can be upgraded 5 times, once each time the player levels up.
I want to calculate the average number of skills the player has at each level, as well as the average tier of their skills.
For example:
Upon reaching level 2, we know that all players will have 1 skill, and that skill will be at tier 1. We know this because the player starts at level 1, and levelling up to level 2 is when their first skill unlocked.
Upon reaching level 3, there is a chance that the player will be able to upgrade that same skill again, while also being guaranteed to have 2 new skills to choose from.
If the player is given the chance to upgrade that same skill and does so, they will have 1 skill, now at tier 2. If they choose one of the other skills, they will have 2 skills, with an average skill tier of 1.
Any help would be great!

Welcome to the MSE. How many levels do we have? When the game ends? 20 options are skills (each with 5 tiers ) or skill-tier (4 skills, each with 5 tiers)?

Actually a pretty nice problem to think about!

Thank you!
The player can level up 40 times. There are 20 skills, each with 5 tiers.

This actually seems like a fairly complicated calculation. Perhaps it would be possible to solve with something like Markov chains. If the random variable $X=\text{current number of skills}$, then you get these transition properties ...

You said: "The player can level up 40 times." So what are the transition probabilities between two consecutive levels? When does the game end? When can a player level up? Put @usernam in your comments when responding to the comments.

@amir apologies, I'm not sure what you mean by 'transition probabilities between two consecutive levels'. To give more context, the game is about killing enemies. Enemies the player kills drop XP; collecting enough XP levels the player up, and prompts them to choose one of 3 randomly selected skills - these can either be a new skill, or an upgrade for an existing skill. This is entirely random.
The game ends when the player dies. The player's level is set back to 1, and they can try again. The game is very similar to Vampire Survivors.

@MattiP. thanks, I'll look into Markov chains some more :)

On "The game ends when the player dies." What is the probability of surviving and passing to the next level? Do you only want the two expectations for those players who reach the 40th level or any player of the game (for this case we need to compute the probability of reaching each level)?

@amir the level they get to, and the level of their skills, will determine the total damage the player is doing, and as such, their chance of surviving until the end of the game. The ultimate goal is to find out their chance of survival beyond each level. But for now, I am trying to find out the probability of their skill levels and number of skills in order to calculate this

I made a quick Python script to simulate a case where 20 skills are incremented completely randomly starting from 0. If a skill is =5 then it cannot be incremented anymore. I ran 5 million simulations for each level, and got the following numbers for the average number of different skills (number of skills with level>0) obtained:
$$
\text{Level 2: Average}~ 1.95
$$
$$
\text{Level 3: Average}~ 2.85
$$
$$
\text{Level 4: Average}~ 3.71
$$
$$
\text{Level 5: Average}~ 4.52
$$
$$
\text{Level 6: Average}~ 5.30
$$
$$
\text{Level 7: Average}~ 6.03
$$

@MattiP. that's amazing, thank you! Would it be possible to access your python script?
In my example, I mentioned 20 skills, but in reality, I don't know yet exactly how many there will be, so if at all possible, seeing how you've done this, or being able to modify certain variables myself, would be amazing. I also would love to be able to see this data for 40 levels if at all possible. Thanks a lot!!

Not really a solution, but here's a Python code that you can use to at least have some heuristics about the average number of acquired skills:
import random

def main():
    max_test = 5000000        # Number of tests carried out
    nOfSkills = 20      # Number of skills, default =20
    levelCap  = 5       # Level cap, after this you cannot level up a skill
    levelUps  = 6       # Number of level-ups considered

    s = 0
    for test in range(max_test):
        skills = [0 for i in range(nOfSkills)]
        for iter in range(levelUps):
            # Enumeration starts from 0, therefore maximum is nOfSkills-1
            c = random.randint(0, nOfSkills-1)
            while skills[c]==5: c = random.randint(0, nOfSkills-1)
            skills[c]+=1
        #Now we are interested in how many non-zero entries there are
        res=0
        for e in skills:
            if(e>0): res+=1
        s+=res
    print(s/max_test)

main()

With the example values, the code will probably return something like 5.298, corresponding to Level 6.
